# Java : casting and generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have some understanding issue with generics

I have this variable : `private static final UnaryOperator<Object> IDENTITY_FN = t -> t;`

I don't understand why this code compiles :

```
public static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identityFunction() {
        return (UnaryOperator<T>) IDENTITY_FN;
    }

UnaryOperator<String> fn = identityFunction();
```

But... this code doesn't compile :

```
UnaryOperator<String> fn = (UnaryOperator<String>) IDENTITY_FN;
```

It looks basically the same for me

Comment: They are not the same. In one case you are casting to `UnaryOperator<T>`, and in the other case you are casting to `UnaryOperator<String>`.  A "why" question like this isn't really answerable, because for every explanation I give, you can keep asking "why is *that* the case?" and we will be here forever. Can you describe what kind of answer you are looking for, and also show what you already know, so that we have some common ground?

Comment: Of course, no one should do this in practice anyway.  The compiler warns that such code is unsafe for a reason.  Most typed generic casts are unsafe.  There is always a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast of the expression `IDENTITY_FN` (which has type `UnaryOperator<Object>`) to type `UnaryOperator<String>` is disallowed at compile time because it is provably impossible for something to be both a `UnaryOperator<Object>` and a `UnaryOperator<String>` at the same time (i.e. there cannot be any type that is a subtype of both). Generic type arguments are invariant, so although `String` is a subtype of `Object`, `UnaryOperator<String>` is not a subtype of `UnaryOperator<Object>`, nor vice versa. And if an implementing class inherits from `UnaryOperator` twice, it is not allowed to inherit it with different type arguments in the two inheritances.

On the other hand, the cast of `IDENTITY_FN` (which has type `UnaryOperator<Object>`) to type `UnaryOperator<T>` is *not* disallowed at compile time, because it is possible for something to be a `UnaryOperator<Object>` and a `UnaryOperator<T>` at the same time -- namely, if `T` were `Object`, then `UnaryOperator<Object>` would be a subtype of both. Although it's also possible for this cast to be incorrect (i.e. when `T` is anything other than `Object`), since there is at least one case where it could be valid, the compiler cannot disallow it.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the second code snip it doesn't compile because the cast to `UnaryOperator<String>` would be unsafe and is not allowed to compile because of this. The `identityFunction()` is safe because it uses type erasure allowing it to work with generic types. The cast `(UnaryOperator<T>) IDENTITY_FN` is safe because of type erasure. At runtime, the Java type system erases the type variable T and replaces it with its bound or Object if it's unbounded. So at runtime, `UnaryOperator<T>` just becomes `UnaryOperator`, and `IDENTITY_FN` can be safely cast to this raw type.

When you assign the result of `identityFunction()` to a variable of a specific type like `UnaryOperator<String>`, the Java compiler checks that the types are compatible.